# Is this video of Bruce Lee playing ping pong with nunchucks real?

Tags: video, bruce-lee

This [video](http://youtu.be/SncapPrTusA) shows Bruce Lee playing table-tennis with nunchucks instead of a racket.

The description says something about Lee doing the commercial to promote cell phones for Nokia which makes me think it's fake but I don't know enough about all the timelines to say that for sure. Could this be real?

Comment: Timeline: Bruce Lee 1940-1973, Nokia N96 first available 2008. I think we can safely say he never (in person) advertised this model of Nokia :)

Comment: @Jamiec - Nokia has been around since 1895 and the first cell phone was invented in 1973 ;-)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia

Comment: nokia _has_ been around for a long while, but that specific model of phone wasnt

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No.

[Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/photos/advertisements/pingpong.asp) have done the research.

> This video clip purportedly showing actor and martial arts master Bruce 
>   Lee playing ping-pong with nunchaku (also called "nunchucks" or "nunchuks") is a digital creation intended as a viral advertisement for the Nokia N96 Limited Edition Bruce Lee cell phone, produced in 2008 (thirty-five years after Lee's death) [...]

The article goes on to quote the Chief Creative Officer responsible for the advert.